# "Unable to find type [WinSCP.RemotePath]" when using WinSCP .NET assembly from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to download the last modified file using WinSCP .NET assembly as a part of an ETL procedure. I'm stuck since I have very little to no knowledge of Powershell scripting.

This is what I've tried so far in Windows 10 PowerShell:

```bsh
param (
    $localPath = "C:\download\*",
    $remotePath = "/home/folder/"
)

try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"  
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
        HostName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        UserName = "XXXXXXXX"
        Password = "xxxxxxx"
        }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Get list of files in the directory
        $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

        # Select the most recent file
        $latest =
            $directoryInfo.Files |
            Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
            Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1

        # Any file at all?
        if ($latest -eq $Null)
        {
            Write-Host "No file found"
            exit 1
        }

        # Download the selected file

        $session.GetFiles(
            [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($latest.FullName), $localPath).Check()
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

I've been trying to debug it and noticed it runs up until the `$session.GetFiles` call, outputting the following error:

> Error: Unable to find type [WinSCP.RemotePath].

I have no idea why that would be the case.

Comment: For the plain ftp I'd just use built in .net webclient class. There is plenty of examples on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just comes off as the module is really not being see.

Try using the wrapper from the MS PowerShellGallery as part of this effort for either validation or in place of the one you are using.

```
Find-Module -Name WinScp* | ft -a

Version  Name   Repository Description                          
-------  ----   ---------- -----------                          
5.13.7.0 WinSCP PSGallery  PowerShell Module Wrapper for WinSCP.
```

Even on the WinSCP site instructions for using it, it's a little different than what you show here:

> https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#loading
>
> Loading Assembly   PowerShell script needs to load the assembly before
>   it can use classes the assembly exposes. To load assembly use Add-Type
>   cmdlet

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
```

> Had you need to run the script from other directory, you need to
>   specify a full path to the assembly. You can derive the path from the
>   script file path using $PSScriptRoot automatic variable:5

```
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "WinSCPnet.dll")
```

> If you are writing a script that you plan to use as a WinSCP extension
>   (a custom command), you can use the copy of the assembly installed
>   with WinSCP. In that case you can use the WINSCP_PATH environment
>   variable to resolve the path to the assembly. To allow the script run
>   even outside of WinSCP, you should fall back to the $PSScriptRoot
>   approach (as above), if the variable is not defined:

```
$assemblyPath = if ($env:WINSCP_PATH) { $env:WINSCP_PATH } else { $PSScriptRoot }
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $assemblyPath "WinSCPnet.dll")
```

In your debug and validation effort. Try putting reference at the very top of the script.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll" 

param (
    $localPath = "C:\download\",
    $remotePath = "/home/folder/"
)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you get the problem for `WinSCP.RemotePath` and not for earlier used WinSCP classes like `WinSCP.SessionOptions` or `WinSCP.Session`, you are most likely using an old version of WinSCP .NET assembly that did not have [`WinSCP.RemotePath` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotepath) yet.

Make sure you update to the last version of the assembly.